# What is wrong with this? Trying to use request callback in a prototype...with little success

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/knu2xs/5acc6f24c5df1c881cf7) is how I have been attempting to include a request with a callback to extract a few elements from a series of webpages using Node.js with Request and Cheerio. Originally I had the basic logic working using little more than a function. However, I am trying to make this a little more object oriented, and obviously failing miserably. Since the logic worked before, I am completely stumped as to why it is not working now.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

The Gist: https://gist.github.com/knu2xs/5acc6f24c5df1c881cf7

Answer (score 1):

One of your problem is here, line 82:

```
if (!error) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    // get properties from the html
    this.name_river.get($);
    this.name_reach.get($);
    this.difficulty.get($);
    this.length.get($);

}
```

That inner callback function isn't bound to the same scope, so `this` isn't the `Reach` instance.

You need to grab a reference and use that instead:

```
function Reach(reach_id) {
    /* ...  */

    var self = this;
    this.request = request(url_root + this.reach_id, function (error, response, body) {
        /* ...  */
        self.name_river.get($);
        /* ...  */
    });
}
```

... or explicitly bind it to this:

```
function Reach(reach_id) {
    /* ...  */

    this.request = request(url_root + this.reach_id, (function (error, response, body) {
        /* ...  */
        this.name_river.get($);
        /* ...  */
    }).bind(this));
}
```

MDN article on `this` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

---

Another issue is the call here, line 104:

```
reach.request();
```

Request wasn't set to a function, if I'm reading it correctly. Line 79 executes the request during instance creation:

```
this.request = request(url_root + this.reach_id, function (error, response, body) {
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this. I will take a look at it tonight. Thank you so much for specific advice and references, helping me to slowly (very slowly) figure out how to code in something more than Python.

Comment: The this reference being out of scope, thank you for catching that. I had been looking at my computer for too long.

However, the second issue, how to create the request callback, I am wrestling with. Would you happen to have a good reference or explanation for this?

Comment: Also, I updated the Gist to reflect the self to this reference.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you're trying to do with the request, could you elaborate?